# Cors not apply in laravel5.2

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5

Cors working in this api users/login problem in postjob/store api i solved this issue adding cors true in angular.
After few days i call this api again same error occur

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.10.5/jobpost1/public/api/job. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9001' is therefore not allowed access.

**Routes.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () {

Route::post('users/login', array('middleware' => 'Cors', 'uses' =>      'Auth\AuthController@login')); 
});`

Route::group(['prefix'=>'api'], function()
{

 Route::group(['middleware'=>'jwt-auth'], function ()
  {
    Route::post('postjob/store', array('middleware' => 'Cors', 'uses'=>   'PostController@store'));

 });

});
```

**Cors.php**

```
 class Cors
 {

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{




    // ALLOW OPTIONS METHOD
    $headers = [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'=> '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true'
    ];
    if($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
        // The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
        return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
    }

    $response = $next($request);
    foreach($headers as $key => $value)
        $response->header($key, $value);
    return $response;
}
```

**angular code**

```
                return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://192.168.10.4/jobpost1/public/api/job',
                 cors: true,
                 xhrFields: { 
                 withCredentials: true
                  },
                params: {
      "token" :token,
      "user_id": userId,
      "job_shift": job_shift,
      "job_type": job_type,
      "job_description":job_description,
      "degree_title": degree_title,
      "city": city,
      "experience": experience,
      "career_level": career_level,
      "gender":gender,
     "total_position": total_position,
    "minimum_edu":minimum_edu,
     "apply_before": apply_before
                }
            }).then(function successCallback(response, status) {
      callback(response, status);
      debugger;
    }
      , function errorCallback(response, status) {
        callback(response, status);
        debugger;
      });
        };
```

Comment: If you use apache check this: https://gist.github.com/ZiTAL/3a96710679bd1c21bb381397925c85c0

Comment: i am using wamp server in windows

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding headers using `foreach`:

```
foreach($headers as $key => $value)
    $response->header($key, $value);
```

Give this a go instead:

```
$response->headers->add($headers);
```